# Using a macro expansion as part of an identifier

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
struct S {};

#define CREATE_INSTANCE S instance_##__LINE__

int main()
{
    CREATE_INSTANCE;
    CREATE_INSTANCE;
    return 0;
}
```

What I want it to do is create two instances of `S` named `instance_7` and `instance_8`. What it actually does is creates `instance___LINE__` twice.

How to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2):

Using some indirection:

```
#define Concat_(a, b) a ## b
#define Concat(a, b) Concat_(a, b)
#define CREATE_INSTANCE S Concat(instance_, __LINE__)
```

Comment: Interesting! Are you saying that macros are expanded in the context of other macro's arguments, but not in the context in which I used it here?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Remember that the cpp is _one pass_ actually.

Comment: And I still don't get why double indirection is required...

Comment: @user0042: but aren't macros supposed to be expanded in the expansion of other macros?

Comment: @Violet You accepted the dupe. It's pretty well explained there.

Comment: @user0042: Indeed, I was unaware `#` and `##` inhibit macro expansion.

Comment: @Violet The preprocessor is a _hairy beast_. I avoid using it whenever I can ;-). I gave your question an upvote, because it's a good signpost. BTW: A "violet giraffe" haz violet ground fur and black/brown patches or other way round?

Comment: @user0042: so do I! But some things seem literally impossible without it. And the actual problem I'm solving is not as silly as my MCVE in the question :)

Comment: @VioletGiraffe _"And the actual problem I'm solving is not as silly as my MCVE in the question"_ Sure, and I'm aware of that _over simplification_ problem ;-)

Comment: @user0042: what is the essence of the _oversimplification problem_? :)

Comment: @Violet _"what is the essence ..."_ That it moves it to be an XY-problem ;-)

Comment: @user0042: Nah, I asked precisely what I needed to know and I've fixed my thing. I'm curious if it could be done without macros, but I seriously doubt that.

Comment: @Violet No, such things can't be actually solved without macros.